# User Control Events

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

I have a user control with a button named upload in it. The button click event looks like this:

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Upload the files to the server
}
```

On the page where the user control is present, after the user clicks on the upload button I want to perform some operation right after the button click event code is executed in the user control. How do I tap into the click event after it has completed its work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create an event in your user control, something like:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
```

and then in your method fire the event...

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Upload the files to the server

   if(ButtonClicked!=null)
      ButtonClicked(this,e);
}
```

Then you will be able to attach to the ButtonClicked event of your user control.

Comment: And then make sure that the Page that contains the usercontrol is listening to the event.... this.myUploadControl.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(MyUploadControl_ButtonClicked);
Where MyUploadControl_ButtonClicked is declared in the Page class as the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Public Property in UserControl's CodeBehind:

```
    public Button btn
    {
        get { return this.Button1; }
    }
```

Then on page_Load you can use it like:

```
    WebUserControl11.btn.Click += (s, ea) => { Response.Write("Page Write"); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing an event handler just to call another event, you can instead directly wire the events together by using an explicit event implementation:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked
{
   add { btnUpload.Click += value; }
   remove { btnUpload.Click -= value; }
}
```

Now anyone who subscribes to your `ButtonClicked` event is actually directly subscribing to the `Click` event of the `btnUpload` control. I find this to be a much more succinct way to implement this.